# Same Hotkey för different purposes - change content

Tags: autohotkey, replacement

I want to use the same hotkeys for different purpose. EX. competition1 have fields for 'first name' 'last name' adress e-mail Competion2 have fields for 'first-name last name' e-mail adress I want to have 2 ahk.scripts with the same j sequence. I activate j to answer the firstr competition I do the second comp. and activate j to answer the second comp. But the hotkey j has kept the values from the 1:st activation. How do I erase existing values i the hotkey.? I participate in lot competions so there is not enough hotkeys fo fullfill my needs.

Comment: Sounds like you need a browser with auto-fill capability.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `#IfWinActive` if you want to create multiple 'j' hotkeys that are title-dependent, or you can also make a single hotkey and then have multiple (regular) `If` statements to check various things like the active window title, class, or other details.

If doing logic checks on the active title seems impractical in a single-line `If` statement, you can also do it in the hotkey body and using multiple commands like `WinGetActiveTitle` and `Instr` to try and parse for certain keywords for example.

If you need to clear a variable you can do something like `var:=""` to assign it a null value.